# Step by step guide to install web Apps Feature in Ubuntu 12.04 with screen-shots and steps till end

Tags: apt, webapps

Can anyone please give me a step-by-step guide to installing the Web Apps feature in Ubuntu 12.04. Please include screenshots and clearly separated steps from beginning to end. It would be very helpful to me and other new users as well.

Thank you for your answer. But it did not help. 
I get the following result.

404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Fetched 5,210 B in 1min 15s (68 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Index

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I am encountering this error for 2 months. Please help me out of this. I get this error while updating as well. Please get me out of this. 
I also tried changing my server to Main Server. This also did not help.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-install-ubuntus-new-web-apps-feature

Comment: Will this run under Ubuntu 12.04.1 64 bit version? I am receiving a problem of unmet dependencies: 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-webapps-preview : Depends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: xul-ext-websites-integration but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Is it there a way to fix this? As the error reads: "but it is not going to be installed"? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After trying a couple of times I found several problems and couldn't install. Additionally there are reports on the link that you provided which are talking about serious problems after installing. Install it at your own risk.

Comment: No experience with it. Just how to install. Try using the launchpad for bugs.